# Is the "Related" column available before posting a question?

Tags: support, user-interface

When asking questions, I noticed that initially the list of related questions (down on the right) is not populated, and only appears after the question is already posted. Is it really so or I am just not attentive enough?

The reason I am asking is that frequently after revisiting my question I find lots of closely related stuff in that list (by the way, I want to praise the programmers which made this, the related questions are really really closely related, I wonder how this was possible to achieve), and in some cases if I would know about it before submitting the question, I would formulate it differently or in some cases maybe even not ask it at all.

Of course I can always edit the question later but understandably I would prefer to edit it before posting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is generated after the question is posted. If you look closely, you'll see that the list is not there on very new questions either. This is one more reason to give good titles (and not things like "My question regarding maths"), since upon writing the title the system will suggest "similar" questions, which may or may not appear later in the Related section.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I did notice the list beneath the title, this one appears immediately even before typing of the title is finished :) But by my observation it is much less clever than the Related list...

Comment: My impression is that the related column is not only generated after the question is posted, but is periodically updated and takes into account words used in answers (and comments?) on the question.